# Analyse an example using the measure-theoretic definition of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, definition

I'm taking an introductory level course in statistics and the definitions of probability spaces and random variables are given in measure-theoretic terms. They are in [this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition).

I'd like to verify my understanding using the example below.

[image]

My understanding is that $\Omega$ is the set of $2^{10}$ different sequences of 10 heads or tails, and $E = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. But I'm not sure what $\mathcal{F}$ (and consequently *P*) looks like. I also guess that a member of $\mathcal{E}$ in this case could be any subset of $E$?

Comment: When $\Omega$ is finite, we may take $\mathcal F = 2^\Omega$ to be the power set of $\Omega$. Let $\omega=H$ correspond to a flip being heads and $\omega = T$ correspond to a flip being tails. Then here $X = \sum_{i=0}^{10} \mathsf 1_{\{H\}}(\omega_i)$, for example.

Comment: By the way, when you say "introductory course in statistics," I assume you mean a graduate-level course? Because I cannot see an introductory undegraduate-level course using the measure-theoretic definition of probability spaces and random variables.

Comment: Yes! Although it's not a course in a graduate maths program. I'm fine with definitions being coined this way, just wish there were detailed examples where I can check my understanding against.

Comment: @Math1000 would it be correct to say that for $F \in \mathcal{F}$, *P(F)* $= 2^{-10}|F|$? Also, to calculate the probability of $X$ having a particular value, we would select the $F$'s satisfying it and add up their *P(F)*'s?

Comment: Your first question is correct. As for the second question, it is better to think of the events $\{X=x\}$. Recall this is shorthand for $\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega) = x\}$. So for each $\omega \in \{X=x\}$, you would sum the $\mathbb P(\{\omega\})$.